# A question on parity from book "Mathematics Circles"

Tags: parity

*Three hockey pucks, A,B, and C, lie on a playing field. A hockey player hits one of them in such a way that it passes between the other too.He does this 25 times. Can he return the three pucks to their starting positions*.(THIS IS A PART OF QUESTION ONLY)

Now, can you describe how this question is related to parity. I am finding some patterns in the position changed but not able to conclude anything. This question is from "Mathematics Circles" Chapter-1 Parity. The answer given behind is not satisfactory.

Comment: It is hard to interpret the intended question from your posting.  Please edit your posting to [1] provide the exact wording of the original question and [2] provide the answer given that you regard as unsatisfactory.  This will help mathSE reviewers to [A] reverse engineer the problem composer's intent and [B] either correct the unsatisfactory given solution or explain it to you in a way that makes sense to you.

Comment: When you edit the post for clarity, I suggest leaving off all of the hockey stuff...it's just a distraction.  I think, but am not at all sure, that you are saying that an ordered triple $(x,y,z)$ can be switched to $(y,x,z)$ or to $(x,z,y)$.  Is that correct?

Comment: Your are welcome to flag me with a comment when the editing is done.  However, please do not provide the requested info in comments.  Instead, please edit your question to provide this info.

Comment: @lulu Normally, I would agree with you.  However, here, there is the danger of something being misinterpreted by the OP (i.e. original poster) when he *translates* the question into math terms.  Therefore, I suggest that the OP provide the exact wording of the original question.

Comment: @user2661923  Fair enough.  Though it is awfully difficult to picture what is being done with these hockey pucks.

Comment: @lulu No, I don't think ordered triples describe this. We have three objects (pucks) on a plane, and might as well consider them point-like. Each move changes the position of just one object. A move changing from position $A$ to $A'$ must have segments $AA'$ and $BC$ intersect, and not at an endpoint.

Comment: To get to the original configuration, what does the parity have to be? You have $25$ reflections. What can you conclude?

Comment: @aschepler  Well...but doesn't that simply take $(A,B,C)$ into $(B,A',C)$?.  I can certainly identify the position of the pucks with ordered triples up to cyclic order.  I'd have thought that was enough.

Comment: @lulu Probably, after you appropriately apply the lynchpin idea that clockwise/counterclockwise orientation of the triangle is important and define what those triples describe. I think to state the problem in that way is skipping the interesting part.

Comment: Guys, you can see the body of my question. All the details there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Consider describing pucks' position by naming them clockwise. For example, you can get "ABC" or "BCA" or whatever.
- Observe that some positions are essentially the same and their naming depends on which puck you start, for example "ABC" = "BCA" = "CAB".
- (here comes the parity) Observe that there are two major classes of states: "ABC" = "BCA" = "CAB" and "ACB" = "CBA" = "BAC". You may call them "odd state" and "even state" or whatever. This is a very crucial step. I'm basically saying: "I'll neglect all the information on pucks' positions, except a tiny bit."
- (here comes the solution) Observe that hitting a puck you always transfer between states. For example "ABC" (odd) can be transformed to "ACB" (even) or "CBA" (even),but never to "BCA" (odd) or "CAB" (odd).
- Consider a sequence of hits that transfer odd -(first hit)-> even -(second hit)-> odd -...-(25-th hit)->even. Make a conclusion on impossibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now the question makes a lot of sense.